# Angular PrimeNg p-calendar in a JHipster project

Tags: angular, jhipster

When I import the p-calendar module and insert the calendar into my page, I see the input field displayed on the page. When I click to test, this error is displayed: ERROR Error: NG05105: Unexpected synthetic listener @overlayAnimation.start found.
I'm new to Java and Angular development.

*I haven't imported any animation packages*

I installed primeng with npm: `npm install primeng`

Imported the module:

```
import { CalendarModule } from 'primeng/calendar';
```

Used in my html file:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date" view="month" dateFormat="mm/yy" [readonlyInput]="true">
</p-calendar>
```

Comment: I found it. I had to import and add to the providers, BrowserAnimationsModule in the app.config.ts file.

Add "importProvidersFrom(BrowserAnimationsModule)" to "providers: [...]"

Comment: You can use a simpler syntax with better performance with `provideAnimationsAsync`(and it'll avoid relying on importProvidersFrom):
`providers: [provideAnimationsAsync()]`: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/animations/async/provideAnimationsAsync#usage-notes